# foreign key column showing empty in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i create 2 table with a foreign key relation

but when i insert data into them foreign key column not showing the id of main table in phpmyadmin !

but it is working ok and showing key in phpstorm and sqlyog !

[IN PHPMYADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpRSj.jpg)

[IN SQLYOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/770WN.jpg)

why phpmyadmin cant show the number of key ?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the InnoDB engine, i think that as possible reason.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Thanks
Amit

Comment: @AliBakhshi can you please tell me which version of phpmyadmin are you using.

Comment: and i have more relation in my database and they working ok